# How to solve conflicts on GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I recently worked with `git` and there was such a question. I made a `merge` request from the current `branch` into `master`. And received such a message:

[image]

What are the options to allow this, so that the button appeared on the site to accept the `merge`? If I do local merge then it closes automatically, but I don’t need to. Are there any options?

Comment: I don't understand the question, did you resolved your conflicts locally?

Comment: Only if I do a merge locally. But this automatically closes the merge request on the site. The question is, can conflicts be resolved in some way, so that the request remains and the "Accept merge request" button appears?

Comment: well resolve locally and push your branch again, then the "button" will be there.... (I must have missed somethng...)

Comment: Yes, but i see the conflict only when i do merge. What if I merge master into current branch, resolved conflict and push master, this may solve my problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally to resolve issues like this I would do the following locally:

```
git pull origin master
```

This should pull the current master from the remote and merge it with your local branch, then you can resolve the conflicts on your local copy, commit that and you should be good to proceed with your merge

I have since been told that the better way to do this is to rebase, by taking all the changes on your local branch since the most recent common commit on the master, you can apply those changes to the current master, when you're on your local branch you can run:

```
git rebase master
```

This will delete your commit and create a new commit with all the changes and you don't need a second commit. This means the git history will be cleaner.

To try to avoid this when going forward, try to make sure you pull master before making a new branch so you're up to date when you start. Obviously if you take a while to ready your commit before trying to merge again you might need to pull the master in again to make sure you don't have a conflict first.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me.